# delete columns based on index name string operation

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a large dataframe with a lot of columns and want to delete some based on string operations on the column names.

Consider the following example:

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data=[(1,2,3, "foo"), ("bar", 4,5,6), (7,"baz", 8,9)],
                     columns=["test", "anothertest", "egg", "spam"])
```

Now, I would like to delete all *columns* where the ***column name*** contains `test`; I have tried to adapt answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536350/8839068) (string operations on column *content*) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574520/pandas-highlight-rows-based-on-index-name) (on addressing the name) to no avail.

```
df_tmp = df_tmp[~df_tmp.index.str.contains("test")]
# AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

df_tmp[~df_tmp.name.str.contains("test")]
# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks a ton in advance. :)

Comment: use : `df_tmp.loc[:,~df_tmp.columns.str.contains("test")]` your code didnot work because you were checking the index and not columns, also the correct way to return the `True` columns is via `df.loc[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better would be with `df.filter()`...

```
>>> df_tmp
  test anothertest  egg spam
0    1           2    3  foo
1  bar           4    5    6
2    7         baz    8    9
```

Result:

1-

```
>>> df_tmp.loc[:,~df_tmp.columns.str.contains("test")]
   egg spam
0    3  foo
1    5    6
2    8    9
```

2-

```
>>> df_tmp.drop(df_tmp.filter(like='test').columns, axis=1)
   egg spam
0    3  foo
1    5    6
2    8    9
```

3-

```
>>> df_tmp.drop(df_tmp.filter(regex='test').columns, axis=1)
   egg spam
0    3  foo
1    5    6
2    8    9
```

4-

```
>>> df_tmp.filter(regex='^((?!test).)*$')
   egg spam
0    3  foo
1    5    6
2    8    9
```

### Regex explanation

```
'^((?!test).)*$'

^         #Start matching from the beginning of the string.    
(?!test)  #This position must not be followed by the string "test".
.         #Matches any character except line breaks (it will include those in single-line mode).
$         #Match all the way until the end of the string.
```

Nice [explanation about regex negative  lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259443/how-to-match-a-line-not-containing-a-word)